# System architecture using Domain driven design, should the domain objects be available to all layers?

Tags: domain-driven-design

- views can call controllers
- controllers only talk to views and service  layer (where the transactions are)
- service layer has a series of calls to domain object(s) wrapped in a transaction
- domain object contains the calls to dao layer.
- dao layer populates domain objects and  persists data.

But I can pass the domain object around the different layers to access data via getters, or do I have to use a dto - a cut down domain object containing data specific to views/use-cases. Passing domain objects around the layers seems to encourage breaking the rule that layers can only talk to the specified other layers. But on the other hand, that is the point of DDD ? If it is preferable to take data from the domain object and put into a dto, where should this take place, the controller ?

[image: Domain-driven-design, am it doing it right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put the domain next to all other layers since it should be 100% independent of everything else. hence you should be able to use it everywhere.

Services in DDD should only be used when two or more different root aggregates need to interact.

As for transactions, why don't you just use `TransactionScope` in the UI layer? It's still persistance ignorant.

I personally use the repositories directly in the UI (since the repository in DDD is a DB abstraction)

Comment: I am actually a java/spring devver. TransactionScope is an ms thing ?  Repositories in the ui layer, yowzers ... that seems mighty weird to me. Domain objects shoul d100% independent of everything ? I'd been working to the idea that they have daos injected.

Comment: Domain objects have to be dependent on the dao layer don't they - otherwise how do they get populated with useful data ?

Comment: And you say a service layer should only be used when two or more different root aggregates need do to integrate ? Whats a root aggregate ? Two different domain objects ? So you have transactions in two different layers (one layer for transactions with two or more root aggregates, and another layer for transactions with only 1 root aggregate ? Whats the point of having layers at all then ?

Comment: Your repositories loads domain objects, not DAOs. That's the single purpose of the repositories: To load/store the domain objects in the data source.

Comment: Regarding root aggregates: You should probably read the Blue Book (Domain Driven Design) and/or read the PDFs that are avilable at: http://domaindrivendesign.org

Answer (score 2):

Personally I always use **View Models** (DTOs for your View).  This helps cut down the amount of data passed to your Views and avoids accidentally revealing secure data.

In theory the UI (or several UIs or web services) should plug on-top of your system.  For example, if you were exposing your system via Web Services, you would probably also want to flatten and reduce the data in some way, to not create a dependency on your domain entities (so you can change them without breaking external systems) and again not expose any ids or sensitive data in your domain entities.

I guess this would apply to any development practice and not just DDD.

Comment: ok thanks, so where do you think the domain object to dto conversion take place ? The conroller seems the right place without thinking too hard about it ?

Comment: I usually do this in the Controller.  Your View Models wouldn't be part of your domain, but just part of your MVC project.

Comment: just to be clear, so you do pass your domain object up to your controller, then create a dto from that in the controller methods?

Comment: Usually.  I've seen other developers create adapters and automappers to do the job, but mostly I can transform the data in a few lines of LINQ, so it still leaves my controllers fairly skinny.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that in a canonical layered architecture things should be as compartmentalized as possible, passing domain entities all the way to the UI seems acceptable to me, especially in simple applications where Presentation layer and Domain layer are on the same tier. It only requires the UI to have a reference to the Domain, which isn't that shocking (the other way around would actually be problematic).

Mark Seemann has a [blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/02/09/IsLayeringWorthTheMapping.aspx) with interesting thoughts on that issue, though I don't share all of his views.